# dx/dt = A*x using Matlab ode23s

Tags: matlab, ode

I am looking to create a general code using the Matlab ODE solver ode23s to solve a system of 5 ordinary differential equations of first order of the type

```
[dx1/dt;dx2/dt;dx3/dt;dx4/dt,dx5/dt] = A (matrix of dimensions 5x5) * [x1(t);x2(t);x3(t);x4(t),x5(t)]
```

which I can then use multiple times just changing the Matrix A. The `tspan` I set to be `[0 50]` and the initial conditions are `x(0)=C=[1;2;5;10;20]`

Some help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the matlab documentation for differential equations you can find similar examples. Did you try to adapt them to your situation? What were the difficulties there?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann, thans for your reply. The examples in the documentation are either for one ODE or for ODEs of higher order, but not for this. I am having a problem defining the system when the functions x1, .. , x5 are not symbolic (I don't want to use dsolve)....

Comment: I'm still not seeing your problem. The MATrix LABoratory has matrix and vector types and arithmetic operations between them. So define `A` and `x0`, make sure that `A*x0` computes, and call `T,X=ode45(@(t,x) A*x, [t0,tf], x0);`.

Comment: It worked like a charm, I just did not know that I can also use matrix-vector multiplication inside the ode-solving functions! Thank you!